# Which are the Python 3.X versions that correspond to MSC v. 1911?

Tags: python-3.x, version, gdal

I want to install GDAL in the most modern Python 3.X release possible. The latest available packages at [GIS Internals](http://www.gisinternals.com/release.php) correspond to MSC. 1911. I have downloaded and tried Python 3.7.3, 3.7.2, 3.6.8 and all of them correspond to MSC v.1916, so there are no GDAL packages for them (yet, I guess). Can anyone tell me which Python versions correspond to v. 1911?

Comment: The new GDAL 3.0.0 was just released. On pypi was updated today. On GIS Internals wait for tomorrow, maybe it will be there... with support for the latest Python Version.

Comment: Thanks for the input!